# How to update value before sorting in freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

I have the following html template

```
[#list PRODUCTS?sort_by("Price_origin_type") as product]
[/#list]
```

I've got the following exception

```
Exception while merging FreeMarker template with values - ?sort_by(...) failed at sequence index 2 (0-based): All key values in the sequence must be numbers, because the first key value was that. However, the key value of the current item isn't a number.
```

Is there a way to set 0 for empty values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't replace empty values with zeros but should exclude them from the list:

```
[#list PRODUCTS?filter(p -> p != "")?sort_by("Price_origin_type") as product]
[/#list]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort your collection in Java code.
   or
2. Make a dedicated sorting field in your Java dto class.

```
class ProductDto {
  private Integer priceOriginType;
  // other fields

  public int getPriceSortingIndex() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(priceOriginType).orElse(0);
  }
}
```

And use `products?sort_by("priceSortingIndex")` in your template.